# Annotations args dynamic

Tags: java, testing, ejb-3.0, integration-testing

Every Devlopers Nightmare is how well does his/her code fit into the final packaging....

problem with EJB3.x is usage of annotations with out being able to re compile the code with fresh set of args for the unit to pass thru integration test

ex:

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "queue/Messagess") })
```

Question is How many J2ee Containers guarantee the queue jms box is always "queue/Messagess"

Well the naming can be "queue/xyzabc" .....

How can such arguments be configured in EJB3.x with out recompiling the code ...???

with regards

karthik

Answer (score 0):

Use activation-config-property in XML.

```
<message-driven>
  <ejb-name>YourMDBName</ejb-name>
  <activation-config>
    <activation-config-property>
      <activation-config-property-name>destination</activation-config-property-name>
      <activation-config-property-value>YourValue</activation-config-property-value>
    </activation-config-property>
  </activation-config>
</message-driven>
```

Just because you use EJB 3.x with annotations for ease-of-development does not mean that using XML to override annotation config data is "wrong".

Comment: Hi
>>ease-of-development does not mean that using XML to override annotation config data is "wrong"

Comment: Hi
>>ease-of-development does not mean that using XML to override annotation config data is "wrong"

Rather then reinventing the Weel , I rather would like to simpfly the Use of Weel.

I mean to say if annotations are replacements of clutter XML's and is ment simpfly the EJB process...then same should also support Run time Configurations.
I would definitely bileave .. Developers would agree with intermediate solution.  .

Comment: There is no standardized "intermediate" solution: either use annotations (which can't be changed without recompiling) or use XML (which is more verbose).